# can we do this, (AB+1)=1 or (A+B+C+1)=1 with boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra

For example, we have (a + c’d’)(a’ + bc’d’) (bc’d’ + c’d’), can we simplify it to

```
  (a + c’d’)(a’ + bc’d’) (bc’d’ + c’d’)
= ( aa' + abc’d’+ a’c'd' + (1+b)c’d’ ) ( bc’d’ + c’d’)
= ( aa' + abc’d’+ a’c'd' + (1+b)c’d’ ) ( (b+1)c’d’)
= ( abc’d’+ a’c'd' + (1)c’d’ ) ( (1)c’d’)
= ( c’d’ (ab+a+1) ) ( c’d’)
= ( c’d’)  ( c’d’)
= ( c'd')
```

Comment: The `(1+b)c'd'` term in the expansion on the second line is wrong.

Comment: Seems like that was meant to be `(1+a)bc'd'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(AB+1)=1 or (A+B+C+1)=1 is the Annulment Law and is correct.

Your application of the Distributive Law is incorrect.

(a + c’d’)(a’ + bc’d’)

( aa' + abc’d’+ a’c'd' + **(1+b)c’d’** ) should be (aa' + abc’d’ + a’c’d’ + **bc’d’c’d’**), which simplifies to (bc’d’ + a’c’d’).

Answer (score 1):

Inserting `a = t; b = f; c = f; d = f`

```
(t + f’ f’)(t’ + f f’ f’)(f f’ f’ + f’ f’)
(t + t t)(f + f t t)(f t t + t t)
(t + t)(f + f)(f + t)
t f t
```

evaluates to `false`, while `(c' d')` would evaluate to `true` for these inputs.

The rest of the truth table is identical though.

```
  (a + c’d’)(a’ + bc’d’)               (bc’d’ + c’d’)
= (aa' + abc'd' + a'c'd' + c'd'bc'd')  (bc'd' + c'd')
=       (abc'd' + a'c'd' + bc'd')      (bc'd' + c'd')
=       (ab + a' + b)(c'd')            (b + 1)(c'd')
=       (ab + a' + b)(c'd')
=       (a' + ab + b)(c'd')
=       (a' + (a+1)b)(c'd')
=       (a' +      b)(c'd')
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative method, but would like to know if we can do those "transform" in boolean algebra though, so can apply them when needed.

Comment: After re-reading your post, Can you please elaborate a bit more since can't understand your points

Comment: I've found a counterexample for the entire calculation, since that was significantly easier than finding the actual error. I'm fairly convinced the `(a+1)=1` transformation is correct, yes.

Comment: One error I've found is in the `(U + V)(X + Y)` to `(UX + UY + VX + VY)` expansion you turn the "VY" term `(c'd')(bc'd')` into `(1+b)(c'd')`, that is definitely wrong.